# Subprocess.run() cannot find path

Tags: python-3.x, path, subprocess

I have a problem with a script I wrote.

I'm just trying to run an executable (I took `arduino.exe` as an example). However, I either get a `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]` or `a non-zero exit status` (depending on `Shell=True` is `off` or `on`, respectively).

The code of my entire script is simple:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino.exe",shell=True,check=True)
```

I am aware that Shell=True poses a security risk, but have found no other way to solve the path not found error. My other guess is that the code struggles with the numbers and spaces in the path?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape  backslash character. 
use `\\` instead of `\` for every backslash,

```
subprocess.run("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\arduino.exe",shell=True,check=True)
```

or you can use raw string literal,

```
subprocess.run(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino.exe",shell=True,check=True)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! For future reference: why the double slashes?