# Subprocess.run() cannot find file, even if path.exists() returns true

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess

I found these two pages:

[Subprocess.run() cannot find path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055207/subprocess-run-cannot-find-path)

[Python3 Subprocess.run cannot find relative referenced file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101192/python3-subprocess-run-cannot-find-relative-referenced-file)

but it didn't help. The first page talks about using `\\` but I already do, and the second one talks about double quotes around one of the arguments.

```
work = Path("R:\\Work")
resume = work.joinpath("cover_letter_resume_base.doc")

current_date = construct_current_date()

company_name = gather_user_information(question="Company name: ", 
                                        error_message="Company name cannot be empty")

position = gather_user_information(question="Position: ", 
                                   error_message="Position cannot be empty")

# Construct destination folder string using the company name, job title, and current date
destination = work.joinpath(company_name).joinpath(position).joinpath(current_date)

# Create the destintion folder
os.makedirs(destination, exist_ok=True)

# Construct file name
company_name_position = "{0}_{1}{2}".format(company_name.strip().lower().replace(" ", "_"), 
                                position.strip().lower().replace(" ", "_"), resume.suffix)

resume_with_company_name_job_title = resume.stem.replace("base", company_name_position)
destination_file = destination.joinpath(resume_with_company_name_job_title)

# Copy and rename the resume based on the company and title.
shutil.copy2(src=resume, dst=destination_file)

if destination_file.exists():
    print(f"{destination_file} created.")
    #subprocess.run(["open", str(destination_file)], check=True)
```

The program gets the company name and position from the user, generates the current date, creates the directories, and then moves/renames the base resume based on the user input.

**Output and Results**:

```
Company name: Microsoft
Position: Software Eng
R:\Work\Microsoft\Software Engineer\20190722\cover_letter_resume_microsoft_software_eng.doc 
created.
```

**Error Message**:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Kiska/python/job-application/main.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/Kiska/python/job-application/main.py", line 53, in main
    raise error
  File "c:/Users/Kiska/python/job-application/main.py", line 48, in main
    subprocess.run(["start", str(destination_file)], check=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The `if` statement returns `True` but `subprocess.run()` cannot see the file, but I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Do you want `"start"` instead of `"open"`?

Comment: @finefoot @Thomas Weller - I found `open` from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/434612/11781428

Comment: @finefoot - see update

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas - I have the code surrounded by a try/except block so the error message above is what I get.

Comment: then remove `try/except` to see full error - it will give you more information

Comment: Alternatively, if removing the `try/except` is too troublesome, then you could just re-raise the exception after you print your own error messages. I assume you already have something like `except Exception as e:`, then all you need to do is put `raise e` at the bottom of your `except` block.

Comment: @furas - Done. See update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On which operating system are you? The backslashes in your path suggest that you're on Windows and you're using `open` to open the document with its default application. However, looking at this question [Open document with default OS application in Python, both in Windows and Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-os-application-in-python-both-in-windows-and-mac-os/434612#434612) you should use `start` instead of `open` for Windows:

```
subprocess.run(["start", str(destination_file)], check=True, shell=True)
```

Also you need to add `shell=True` for `start` to work. However, you should read https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations beforehand.

(I suspect, the error `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` appears, because Windows cannot find `open` - it's not about the document you're trying to open.)

Comment: @Kiska Try using `os.startfile(destination_file)` instead.

Comment: Definitely use `os.startfile` instead of CMD. There's no point in starting cmd.exe; risking whatever way CMD parses the command line; and then having CMD try `CreateProcessW` before finally calling `ShellExecuteExW`. With `os.startfile`, we're directly calling `ShellExecuteW`. But if you do use subprocess with `shell=True`, never pass a list in this case. In almost every case it's wrong in Unix, and in Windows, where we have to build a command line string anyway, `subprocess.list2cmdline` does not implement quoting for CMD (as if anyone could... its rules are such a mess).